# View / print index values?

Tags: webgl, javascript

So i'm currently trying to draw a 3D cube, and from what I understand everything should be working right, but It's coming out weird and I believe it's because the ordering of my indexes is wrong. Is there any way to view what vertex is associated with an index? for instance something along the lines of

```
print(index[5]);
```

that would output something along the lines of:

```
index[5]: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Is this possible at all? or at least to view it in a debugger?